# Was the Giant Toad's damage changed?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

In the 5E Monster Manual, it says the Giant Toad's bite attack does "(1d10 + 2) piercing damage plus 5 (1d10) poison damage", but when opening the Toad entry in the Roll20 Compendium, there is no poison damage. Was it removed or is this possibly just a mistake in Roll20?

Comment: [For Future reference, the errata for the MM](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/MM_Errata.pdf)

Comment: Do you have a link to the listing with incorrect stats? Because right now the one answer makes this question look invalid.

Comment: The problem appears to be when the Giant Toad Roll20 Compendium entry is dragged and dropped into an NPC sheet...the 'On Hit 2' portion of the sheet is incorrectly auto-filled with 'escape DC 13' instead of '1d10 poison', and consequently doesn't show up on the sheet unless it is manually changed.

Answer (score 4):

Neither. The [Giant Toad](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monsters:Giant%20Toad#h-Giant%20Toad) appears in the Roll20 Compendum with matching stats to the Monster Manual.